# Record and get volume to generate a waveform in Android using Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, volume, microphone, recording

I've been learning Cordova, now I am developing an app to record voice and I'd like to get the volume/Db/Amplitude of the sound being recorded.
I know that there's no oficial plugin by Cordova about this, so I searched and tested some plugins out there:

- Wavesurfer.js:

  It's easy and have a lot of features, but in android is not working, i don't know if the problem is webview or what (I have Android 4.1.2)
  here are the details of my problem with this plugin:
  https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/341
- MicVolume.js:

  https://github.com/shukriadams/micVolume
  I try this without success, I don't know exactly what's the problem but I think in this case it's in the cordova.exec

I can't find more plugins. Is there something else I can do or use, or maybe I am doing something wrong? I think it's strange that I can´t find easy this kind of plugin, so maybe the solution it's starting to learn java from scratch? >:(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Luca did you find any solutions to this issue ?

Comment: No, sorry, It's 1 year since the question, so I don't know if there is any plugin out there now. 
If you want to do some specific functionallity it's always better to know Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Crosswalk so that you can access the Web Audio API without a Cordova plugin. From there you could use something like this example:

http://tyleregeto.com/article/extracting-audio-data-with-the-web-audio-api

As of the current Crosswalk version, the Web Audio API is fully supported, and since you are using Cordova, you won't have any Cross-Origin issues to worry about (e.g. you will be on 'localhost' so there won't be any HTTPS problems).

I have built a Metronome in Angular that I used in a recent Ionic app with Crosswalk, and it works perfectly (even on a pretty bad XGODY device I used for testing). See the Gist below:

https://gist.github.com/MT--/ece6e388a693416aa7e7

Comment: I didn't test this, But it seems very interesting.
Anyway if someone wants to use Cordova, Maybe wavesurfer will solve this problem soon: [https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/341](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/341)
Thanks for this I'll give it a try when I have more time

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how relevant this is since the question was asked over 1 year ago.
But it might help other people looking for an answer. MicVolume.js works but it is poorly documented, I spent a lot of time figuring it out. The following code should work:

```
function audioSuccessCallback(e) {
    setInterval(function() {
        micVolume.read(function(reading) {
            console.log(reading.volume);
        },
        function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    }, 200);
}

function audioErrorCallback(e) {
    console.log(e);
}

micVolume.start(audioSuccessCallback, audioErrorCallback);
```

All you need to do is loop the micVolume.read() function and this will return you the "loudness" of the recording. Either through the internal mic or an external mic. Remember to call micVolume.start() after deviceready fires.
If you need to get the frequency of the sound, you could add following code to the plugin "MicVolumePlugin.java":

```
//Now we need to decode the PCM data using the Zero Crossings Method
int numCrossing = 0; //initialize your number of zero crossings to 0
for (int p = 0; p<bufferSize/4; p+=4) {
    if (buffer[p]>0 && buffer[p+1]<=0) numCrossing++;
    if (buffer[p]<0 && buffer[p+1]>=0) numCrossing++;
    if (buffer[p+1]>0 && buffer[p+2]<=0) numCrossing++;
    if (buffer[p+1]<0 && buffer[p+2]>=0) numCrossing++;
    if (buffer[p+2]>0 && buffer[p+3]<=0) numCrossing++;
    if (buffer[p+2]<0 && buffer[p+3]>=0) numCrossing++;
    if (buffer[p+3]>0 && buffer[p+4]<=0) numCrossing++;
    if (buffer[p+3]<0 && buffer[p+4]>=0) numCrossing++;
}//for p

for (int p=(bufferSize/4)*4;p<bufferSize-1;p++) {
    if (buffer[p]>0 && buffer[p+1]<=0) numCrossing++;
    if (buffer[p]<0 && buffer[p+1]>=0) numCrossing++;
}

// Set the audio Frequency to half the number of zero crossings, times the number of samples our buffersize is per second.
float frequency = (44100*4/bufferSize)*(numCrossing/2);
returnObj.put("frequency", frequency);
```

FFT is more accurate but it's a lot slower. This does the job pretty well. (I can't remember where I found this java code, but props to the one who wrote it!)